# Spatial crosscorrelation between a binary and continuous measurement on a graph

Tags: spatial, cross-correlation, graph-theory

I have a graph $G$ with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$. I measure two signals on the vertices of the graph $X$ and $Y$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are both continuous, we can measure spatial crosscorrelations between them using Moran's $i$. If both are binary, we can measure spatial crosscorrelations by examining the cuts they induce into the graph. Is there a well understood metric of measuring spatial cross-correlations if $X$ is binary and $Y$ is continuous?